# Evaluar si existen dos archivos con el mismo nombre pero con distinta extensión dentro de un ArrayList en java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, if, split

como puedo evaluar la existencia de dos archivos con el mismo nombre pero con distinta extensión dentro de un ArrayList? Por ej si dentro de mi `arraylist<String>` existen dos archivos del mismo nombre pero distinta extensión ej si existe **pepe.pnd** que me evalue si dentro del arraylist existen otros archivos con el mismo nombre pero distinta extension. Si existe el mismo archivo con las extensiones **.ana** o **.cnf**, en el caso de existir que no haga nada, caso contrario que haga otra cosa.

Hago lo siguiente pero no me funciona

```
private boolean existeElemento(String elemento) {
        String[] arreglo = elemento.split(Pattern.quote("."));
        String ext = arreglo[arreglo.length - 1];

        String pnd = "pnd";
        String ana = "ana";
        String cnf = "cnf";
        boolean existePnd = false,
                existeAna = false,
                existeCnf = false;

        int filas = arreglo.length;
        boolean encontrado = false;



     for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
                if (arreglo[i].equals(elemento)) {
//                 En el caso que sean iguales evaluó su extensión
                    encontrado = true;
//                  Evaluó si es .pnd
                    if (ext.equals(pnd)) {
                        existePnd = true;
                    }
    //                Evaluo si es ana
                    if (ext.equals(ana)) {
                        existeAna = true;
                    }
    //                Evaluo si es cnf
                    if (ext.equals(cnf)) {
                        existeCnf = true;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Las cadenas son iguales " + arreglo[i]);
                }
            }

    //        Pregunto si existe pnd y no ana y no cnf.
            if (existePnd && (!existeAna && !existeCnf)) {
                //Codigo si solo existen archivos .pnd
                System.out.println("Alerta");
            }
            return encontrado;
        }
```

Aqui recorro el arraylist con un foreach

```
    private void evaluarArchivos() {
        for (String archivo : arrayArchivos) {

            if (existeElemento(archivo)) {
                System.out.println("Existe");
            }
        }

    }
```

Pero al ejecutar no me hace nada, no me imprime nada en pantalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Después de unos tres meses e terminado mi sistema y e logrado hacer lo que buscaba en esta pregunta, esta es otra solución.**

Lo que quería lograr era levantar los archivos existentes de una carpeta especificada e evaluar sus extensiones, para lo cual utilice 3 arraylist, en uno cargue todos los archivos con las extensiones que necesito(**.pnd**), en otro cargo los demás archivos con otras extensiones(**.cnf  .ana**) y en el tercer arraylist cargo únicamente los archivos únicos sin repetir sus nombres con extensiones **.pnd** únicas, **ya que dentro de la carpeta especificada puede a ver dos o mas archivos con el mismo nombre pero con distinta extensiones.** Si esta condición se cumple no agregaría al tercer arraylist el cual contendría archivos **.pnd** únicos. Hice lo siguiente.

Devlaramos los tres arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosPnd = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosNoPnd = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosPndUnicos = new ArrayList<>();
```

Cargamos el **arrayArchivosPnd** con el metodo **buscarArchivosPnd()**

```
private void buscarArchivosPnd(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivosPnd(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extension. 
                        if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd")) {
                            arrayArchivosPnd.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Luego cargamos el **arrayArchivosNoPnd** con el metodo **buscarArchivosNoPnd()**

```
private void buscarArchivosNoPnd(File ruta) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivosNoPnd(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                        if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                            arrayArchivosNoPnd.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Aquí buscamos los archivos únicos que existan en los dos arraylist cargados previamente, si cumplen la condición de que no se repitan llenamos el tercer array

```
public void buscarArchivosPndUnicos(File ruta) {
//            Por cada vuelta que da el bugle vaciamos los tres arraylist para que no se conviertan en acumuladores.
            this.arrayArchivosPndUnicos.clear();
            this.arrayArchivosPnd.clear();
            this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.clear();
//            Instanciamos los dos metodos anteriores para evaluar la condicion, pasandole por parametro la ruta.
            this.buscarArchivosPnd(ruta);
            this.buscarArchivosNoPnd(ruta);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arrayArchivosPnd.size(); i++) {
//                Si no existen en el arrayArchivosNoPnd un archivo con el mismo nombre que es pasado por parametro
//                en la posicion i del arrayArchivosPnd signidica que ese archivo es unico y se lo agrega al arrayArchivosPndUnicos.
                if (!this.existeEnLosNoPnd(this.arrayArchivosPnd.get(i))) {
                    arrayArchivosPndUnicos.add(this.arrayArchivosPnd.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
```

Método booleano que retorna verdadero si los archivos son iguales o falso en el caso que sean archivos únicos.

```
private boolean existeEnLosNoPnd(String nombreArchivoPnd) {
//            Se convierte a un arreglo de array el string recibido.
            String[] arrayNombreExtensionPnd = nombreArchivoPnd.split(Pattern.quote("."));
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.size(); i++) {
//                Se recorre el arrayArchivosNoPnd y se lo convierte en un arreglo de array.
                String[] arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd = this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.get(i).split(Pattern.quote("."));
//                Se comparan los dos arreglos, si son iguales significa que los archivos son iguales.
                if (arrayNombreExtensionPnd[0].trim().equals(arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd[0].trim())) {
//                System.out.println("son iguales");                
                    return true;
                }
            }
//        System.out.println("es un pnd único");        
            return false;
        }
```

Espero que a alguien le sea útil, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate bien lo que estás haciendo. Recorres el listado de elementos pero, ¿qué estás comparando?

Si sigues bien tu programa, lo que haces es pasarle un nombre de archivo, lo descompones y lo comparas consigo mismo... no suena bien.

Lo que tienes que hacer es posicionarte sobre un elemento y recorrer el resto de la lista comparando.

```
for (int i=0; i<arrayarchivos.length-1; i++)
    for (int j=i+1; j<arrayarchivos.length; j++){
        //Comprobamos que los nombres sean los mismos
if(arrayarchivos[i].substring(0,arrayarchivos[i].lastindexof(".")).equals(arrayarchivos[j].substring(0,arrayarchivos[j].lastindexof("."))){
//Tienen el mismo nombre, comprobamos que la extension sea diferente
        if(!arrayarchivos[i].substring(arrayarchivos[i].lastindexof("."), arrayarchivos[i].lenght).equals(arrayarchivos[j].substring(arrayarchivos[j].lastindexof("."), arrayarchivos[j].length))
            //Si tiene el mismo nombre y diferente extensión pintamos en pantalla
            System.out.println("Son iguales con diferente extensión");
    }}
```

Espero que vaya, no lo he probado, pero lo importante es que veas que tienes que situarte en un elemento y recorrer la lista comparando con el resto de elementos y en el código que has subido no lo haces. Para ver que hace tu código, depúralo paso a paso para ver bien lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: **Si me funciono a la perfección, le faltaba algunos arreglitos pero la esencia es la misma, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!**

Comment: Me alegro, un saludo y ánimo!

Answer (score 0):

O yo no entiendo o realmente no se entiende tu ejemplo. Es como que dentro del método existeElemento supones que estás manipulando todos los nombres de archivo, cuando en realidad manipulas un solo nombre de archivo.

podrías intentar algo como

```
Map<String, String> nombresUnicos = new HashMap<String, String>(); //nombre, extension
boolean hay = false;
for(String nombreArchivo : nombres) {
   String[] archivoExtension = nombreArchivo.split(".");
   if(nombresUnicos.containsKey(archivoExtension[0]) {
       hay = !nombresUnicos.get(archivoExtension[0]).equals(archivoExtension[1])
   }
   if (hay) {
       break;
   } else {
       nombresUnicos.put(archivoExtension[0], archivoExtension[1]);
   }
}
```

Disculpame si digo cualquiera, no estoy programando mucho en java :)

Answer (score 0):

Algo así te valdría:

```
private String quitarExtension(String nombreFicheroCompleto){
    //Se asume que los ficheros son todos del tipo xxxxx.xxx, es decir, no hay puntos en el nombre del fichero más que para separar nombre y extensión
    return nombreFicheroCompleto.substring(0,nombreFicheroCompleto.indexOf("."));
}
private boolean existeElemento(List<String> listaFicheros, String nombreSinExtension){
    int numeroFicherosCoincidentes = listaFicheros.stream()//Se crea un stream sobre la lista
    .map(item->quitarExtension(item))//Se convierte para tener una lista sin extensiones
    .filter(item->nombreSinExtension.equalsIgnoreCase(item))//Se compara el nombre de fichero de entrada con cada elemento de la lista, manteniendo solo los coincidentes
    .count();//Se cuenta el número de elementos coincidentes
    return numeroFicherosCoincidentes > 0; //Devolver true si ya hay un fichero con el mismo nombre, excluyendo su extensión
}
```